# ¿Por qué me salta un error en index en Python?

Tags: python

Debo crear una función que analice la diagonal de una matriz cuadrada. Debe comparar el último dígito del número con el primero del siguiente número de la diagonal. La función debe ser recursiva. Estoy utilizando Python 3.8.1

```
def diagonal_IZQ(M,i,j): #Diagonal de izquierda a derecha
    if i>=len(M):        #j debe empezar en 0 #M sería la matriz
        return True      #i debe empezar en 0
    else:
        if ((M[i][j])%10)==(M[i+1][j+1]//10**(len(str(M[i+1][j+1]))-1)): #IndexError: list index out of range
            return diagonal_IZQ(M,i+1,j+1)
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Me salta un error de index y no sé cómo lo podría corregir
Dice que ese error está en
 if ((M[i][j])%10)==(M[i+1][j+1]//10**(len(str(M[i+1][j+1]))-1))

Comment: ¿Y cual es el error que dices?

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final del recorrido por la diagonal, `i` vale `len(M) - 1`, por lo que `i` apunta a la última fila de la matriz `M`. La variable `j`, igualmente, apunta a la última columna.

En ese momento, la condición

```
if i>=len(M):        #j debe empezar en 0 #M sería la matriz
```

no se cumple, por lo que se ejecuta el `else`:

```
if ((M[i][j])%10)==(M[i+1][j+1]//10**(len(str(M[i+1][j+1]))-1)):
```

Aquí estás haciendo comparando la última casilla de la diagonal (`[i][j]`) con la siguiente (`[i+1][j+1]`), que no existe. Eso se manifiesta como un error de indice, pues en

```
M[i+1][j+1]
```

los indices valen exactamente `len(M)`, y por tanto, están pasados en 1.

Solución:

```
if i >= len(M) - 1:        #j debe empezar en 0 #M sería la matriz
```

Hay que terminar el recorrido en la penúltima casilla de la diagonal.

Comment: Excelente. Le agradezco mucho su ayuda!

Comment: Como eres nuevo @Jaurush, posiblemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow, es dandole una puntuación positiva a la pregunta y por qué no, si te ha parecido una respuesta que ha ayudado a tu problema, marcar la pregunta como "respuesta correcta". Esto no solo agradecerá la ayuda, si no que además, posicionará bien tu pregunta y si en el futuro, alguien tiene una duda parecida a la tuya, tendrá más facilidades para encontrarla :)